# Python Machine Learning Prediction Model - Predict String Variable based on multiple other string variables

Tags: regression, machine-learning, python, predictive-models, learning

I'm very new to Machine Learning, so please forgive the simplicity here. It's probably because I'm new to this, but I can't seem to find anything relevant enough online to help here.
I have data on laptops, phones, and printers like this:

Manufacturer, Model Name, Model Id, (and a few others).

For Example:

Dell, Latitude 3000, Latitude 3340

Lenovo, ThinkPad X1, X1 Carbon

Dell, 1100, 1130 Laser

Each item is assigned a category, like laptop, phone, or printer.  I have thousands of items, most have categories, but a handful don't (Several of my categories are blank) and I'd like to be able to try to predict which category it's in based on the Manufacturer, Model Name, and Model Id provided.  I understand this may not "fit" a model perfectly, but I was hoping someone here could help with with this.  I'm really a beginner and don't even know what libraries I might need.  Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that most of the strings for e.g Manufacturer or Model Name etc will occur many times, you can treat them as categorical features. You can then numerically encode them (for example, with one-hot encoding) and fit a classifier. This seems like a fairly suitable problem for a tree-based model, so I'd check out scikit-learns implementations of decision tree and random forest classifiers.

Comment: As a beginner, I'm sorry, but this went a bit over my head.  Do you have any example sites I could look at for decision tree and random forest implementations?

Comment: @user2066464 I'd recommend checking out scikit-learn's user guide. Both the section on DTs ( https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/tree.html#tree ), and their coverage of supervised learning in general should be a handy introduction to the subject. ( https://scikit-learn.org/stable/user_guide.html ). If you're looking for a textbook, Elements of Statistical Learning ( https://hastie.su.domains/Papers/ESLII.pdf ) is available online for free.

Comment: You can roughly distinguish between two types of vairables: numeric like for example age or categorical such as gender or the type of your car. Numeric values are easy to use as they are already represented by number. For categories you need to first convert them two numbers. Male = 0, Female=1, and non-binary=2. However, now you introduced a natural ordering Male is below female and female below non-binary. It practise there is no ranking, so we use of one-hot encoding. Each category is represented thu a vector

https://machinelearningmastery.com/why-one-hot-encode-data-in-machine-learning/